# Play memory streams avoiding gap between them in WP8.1 app

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, memorystream

I have 2 memory streams which are representing wav files in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. I want to play them but **avoiding gaps** between them, is there any way to do that without using `Sleep` methods or something like that?

I've tried already the `Thread.Sleep()` but I think it is making lot of gaps as my 2 files are 20ms duration each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the audio is the same format and the wave headers have been stripped you could just concatenate the memory streams.

```
streamTwo.CopyTo(streamOne);
```

If the wave headers are still embedded then you'd need to skip over the one in the second stream - generally 44 bytes. If the formats are different then you'll need to find another technique.

Comment: Hello, are the headers have to be written only once in start of the stream?